# IDLE generating syntax error for regex if string in function

Tags: python, python-idle

I'm trying to run a small webscraper in Python's IDLE and I'm encountering a syntax error that doesn't make sense to me. If I compile this pattern outside of a function, it works fine:

```
restaurant_name = re.compile("""Name: ([\w ']+)""", re.IGNORECASE)
```

If I put this inside a function, it generates a syntax error "SyntaxError: Invalid escape sequence \w" (see photo below).

This only occurs in IDLE. If I run it elsewhere there is no issue. Any thoughts as to why this is occurring? Am I missing something obvious?

Happens for me on IDLE (windows): 3.8.11 and 3.8.12.

Here's what I see:

[image: The syntax error I see]

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on my IDLE with Python 3.8.10 on Linux.

Comment: Use a raw string: `r'....'`.

Comment: The documentation on string literals has this note: "Changed in version 3.6: Unrecognized escape sequences produce a DeprecationWarning. In a future Python version they will be a SyntaxWarning and eventually a SyntaxError." Maybe the Windows port of IDLE is jumping the gun in some way? (I've never seen a deprecation warning be raised in any version of Python, let alone a syntax warning or syntax error, though.)

Comment: Confirmed the raw-string causes the syntax error to go away @KlausD.  Still a bit unclear why the syntax error would be raised only when inside a function, though.